# Fragment gets closed after Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, android-camera

Hi I have an activity and 2 fragments A and B. when app starts fragment A is shown when I go to fragment B and press the button the camera shows up and after taking the photo and saving instead of showing fragment B again it goes back to fragment A. I have no idea why!
Here is my fragment B.
This is how i start fragment B:

```
 Fragment f = UploadDataFragment.newInstance(rawResult.getText());
    if (f != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

My camera button:

> ```
>      picButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>             String file = "img.jpg";
>             File newfile =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), file);
>             Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);
>             cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
>             cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
>             startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
>         }
>     });
> ```

Here is my activityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/img.jpg");
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        //POST Image to Server
        mUploadPhotoRequest.execute();
    }
   }
```

I dont know if it matters but here is my AsyncTask class:

```
/**
 * Async task class to upload photo by making HTTP call
 * */
private class UploadPhotoRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Video...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        User user = new User(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> list=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        list.add(new     BasicNameValuePair("file",getRealPathFromURI(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),videoUri)));
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(Constants.addPhotoUrl + "api_key=" + user.getApiKey()+"&barcode=" + barcode, ServiceHandler.POST,list);
        Log.e("Tag","VIDEO RESPONSE "+ jsonStr);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any logic regarding fragments in your activity's `onResume()`?

Comment: @dcharms Thanks man you are right I was opening fragment A in my onResume activity :) Solved my problem

Comment: @HiradRoshandel can you please help with the OnResume logic that you wrote

Comment: @user3551487 Unfortunately I can't remember since I asked this 2 years ago! But I believe I was opening fragment A in OnResume which was the problem